# Отображение данных с БД в реальном времени без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, mysql

у меня есть Страничка и База Данных

**Содержимое БД:**

```
id | text
----------------------------
1  | Это первая строка
2  | Вторая строка
3  | Ещё какой то рандомный текст..
4  | И тут тоже что то такое типо
5  | Содержимое БД - не важно, тут просто ид строки
6  | И текст
7  | Гы, просто рандомный текст
(И ещё много строк данных с текстом)
```

**Страничка PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title> - without reboot page - </title>
<style>
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block">
    <!-- ТУТ СОДЕРЖИМОЕ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ, ПРИМЕР: -->
    <p>Это первая строка</p>
    <p>Вторая строка</p>
    <p>Ещё какой то рандомный текст..</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

И нужно сделать так, чтобы в блоке div.block отображались содержимое Базы Данных так, чтобы страничка не перезагружалась, если я добавлю в БД новую строку, то она почти сразу же отобразилась на страничке, или если удалю строку, то тоже с сайта она бы исчезла

И скролл бар чтобы не поднимался, а был примерно на том же месте..

Подскажите как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: ну очевидно что вам не хватает AJAX  запроса повешенного на условно ежеминутное обновление

Comment: что-нить вида `setTimer(function(){ $.get("script.php", { lastId: xx}), function(html){ $("#content").append(html);}}, 1000)` на фронте

Comment: @teran, спасибо большое!